# How to split element of custom Data type

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie to haskell.

I am quite confused of custom data type

So what I want to make it is to show total age of person and each person's name and age

so I expects it looks like this

```
Detail "Ben" 20 Student
       "Joy" 25 Police
       "Hellen" 10 Student
Total   55 -- 20 + 25 + 10
```

So this is my code

```
 data Person = Name String Int Job deriving Show -- name age Job
 data Det = Total Int | Detail String Int Job deriving Show -- age | name age Job
 data Job = Police | Student deriving Show 


Split :: Person -> Int -- Need to get eacn age to accumulate one another for total age 
Split (Name _ age _ ) = age

check1 :: [Person] -> Det -- Need to sum all the age with Split function 
......?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total :: [Person] -> Int
total [] = 0
total (x:xs) = getAge x where
      getAge (Name _ age _ ) = age + total xs
```

You need to use a list of the Person type. This will return the total age of all elements in the list.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing ? How can I concatenate names like "Ben Joy Hellen"